# Running sails.js app as Azure WebJob

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, azure-webjobs

I currently have a Sails.js backend-only app that, every hour:

- fetches a given World of Warcraft realm's AH dump
- processes it
- removes the old dump from the DB
- outputs both the dump and the job result to the DB.

I've found out that Azure WebJobs would make this easier, since I'd not need to manually code which realms to cover or the scheduling itself.

Is there any way to turn an Sails.js app into a WebJob? Or should I be using Waterline itself for the DB access and coding everything else manually?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Sails.js per se, but in general if you can extract your logic into a nodejs console app that you can run on your machine, then it should work as a webjob. All you would need to do is upload the full directory, that's including all the `node_modules` and all the `.js` files, make sure your entry point is set in a file called `run.js` and you should be set.

If you want it to be triggered on a schedule, include a file called `settings.job` that contains your schedule in the following format

```
{"schedule": "cron expression for the schedule"}
```

for hourly the cron expression would be `0 * * * * *`